# MongoDB query referenced documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to use Mongodb Referenced documents to make it similar to a sql relational database. 
Having a collection like posted_event, users, event

I did some searching and that I understand that I can have an objectid from collection A and that collection B would have a field with references to collection A's objectID.

With this design, in my application I would simply query from collection A and then pass in the values and "store" / display them into a result from collection B.

Is this a correct usage and approach to display the final result to end user?

If it is correct how would I "replace" the value from collection B taken from collection A?

Im thinking it would just be 2 find() queries

Collection B is the end result

```
 {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec032f4b0dbf9d43006aa78"
    },
    "activity_creator_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec02da3b0dbf9d43006aa5e"
    },
    "activity_receiver_id": [{
        "$oid": "5ec02e8bb0dbf9d43006aa61"
    }],
    "activity_name": {
         "$oid": "5ec03137b0dbf9d43006aa73"
    },
    "activity_status": {
        "$oid": "5ec02bdab0dbf9d43006aa56"
    }
}
```

Collection A contains let say names

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec02da3b0dbf9d43006aa5e"
    },
    "first_name": "Bobby",
    "last_name": "Lin",
    "email": "bobby.lin@gmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb provides $lookup operator for joining two collections. Its basically like a join in sql, where you'd do a match between _id in A and activity_creator_id in B.
If you're using mongoose odm you'd directly do a populate in the find query in collection B itself.

Comment: Ahh got it! Thanks for the hint. I am wondering so when I decide to use java/javascript to make an api/database call I would essentially use the $lookup operator to "join" the information then cleanse and drill down for the data that I need?

Comment: Yes, although i would advise you to use mongoose if you're using JavaScript, makes life easier.